# Clean Apache2 configuration on OS X El Capitan following upgrade

Tags: macos, apache

I've spent a while trying to get my apache2 configuration working again after upgrading to OS X El Capitan without success. I've now messed with enough things trying to fix it that I think the best thing to do now is start over as if setting up Apache 2.4.16 from scratch on a fresh install of El Capitan.

I don't know how to get back to the equivalent of a new, clean Apache 2.4.16 configuration though. I can't do that by copying from the files in /etc/apache2/original because those are from my old Apache 2.2.x before upgrading OS X to El Capitan.

Any ideas?

Comment: It turns that the premise of my question was incorrect. Upon actually inspecting the files in /etc/apache2/original, they look like clean Apache 2.4.x configuration files and not like my old files from Apache 2.2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /etc/apache2 directory, there should be an original version of your httpd.conf file. Just restore.

I'm not sure what you changed but you can start there, if you can't trace your steps back, then yes, do a clean install and start over.